# Make Webpack output files relative to the input files

Tags: javascript, webpack, build-process, build-tools

Let's assume I want my compiled JavaScript files to exist side-by-side with my source files, resulting in a directory structure like:

```
- TimeframeToolbar
    - TimeframeToolbar_compiled.js
    - TimeframeToolbar_src.js
    - dependencies
        - *contains js files that are imported by TimeframeToolbar_src.js*
```

Is it possible to do this with Webpack? From what I can tell, the output path only allows a single directory, meaning that the source and compiled file trees must be totally separate.

Comment: You would need to specify an entry for each file (glob it) and use an output pattern. If possible, it might actually make sense to go through Babel directly assuming you are using it.

Comment: Can you explain how I would use an output pattern for the path? I see that I can do things like `filename: "[name].bundle.js"`, but I don't see an option for doing that with the path. In fact, the [docs state for output.path](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output-path): `The output directory as absolute path (required).` I also don't know what Babel solution you're suggesting. I am indeed using Babel, but it's not clear to me how that would make a difference.

Comment: Ok, I see now. To get enough control you would need to generate a structure like this `module.exports = [{... config ...}, {... config ...}]`. I think that would give enough control over the output. In this particular case you might find it more convenient to go directly through Babel as webpack doesn't work well for this use case.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to make the keys of your entry configuration object the path you want for the output files. For example:

```
entry: {
    'feature-1/feature-1': './dev/feature-1/feature-1.jsx',
    'feature-2/feature-2': './dev/feature-2/feature-2.jsx',
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: './build',
}
```

This will result in the following compiled files:

`./build/feature-1/feature-1.js`
`./build/feature-2/feature-2.js`

So essentially the `[name]` placeholder in `output.filename` ends up being a directory path rather than just a file name.